# Access HTTPS URL from command prompt in Windows

Tags: windows, https

I have an update URL that I need to access. It has all the parameters in the URL to do its job. I don't need to see it in the browser nor do I need its contents to be saved. Is there a program that will simply fetch an HTTPS URL from the command line for Windows? (preferably free ;) Thanks!

Comment: Did you try [`wget`](https://code.google.com/p/osspack32/downloads/detail?name=wget-1.14.exe) already?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm having some trouble with the URL. There are 4 parts to the query string: host, domain, password, and ip.
    The errors I get are:
    'domain' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'ip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

Comment: It seems to stop realizing the URL at the first ampersand. My URL is along these lines: https ://host.com/update?host=subdomain&domain=mydomain.com&password=mypass&ip=27.42.35.99 (space was inserted so it would display right)

Comment: Enclose the URL inside straight quotes (`"`); `&()[]{}^=;!'+,``~` are reserved characters of the Windows command line interpreter.

Comment: Ahhhh I see! One last thing. SSL is so confusing. What I need to accomplish is to have the URL encrypted by HTTPS before it's sent out (because a password is right in the URL itself). If I use the `--no-check-certificate` directive, will my URL still remain secure and encrypted across the internet? (And if you put your response as an answer instead of a comment, I can upvote you :)

Comment: You shouldn't skip the certificate check unless you really have to. What's the actual command you're using? Did you include the `--secure-protocol` parameter? Anyway, added answer with additional info.

Comment: This is an update URL for dynamic DNS with Namecheap. It says I can't locally verify the issuer's authority. How do I fix this? Here's the output: Connecting to dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com (dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com)|
199.188.202.39|:443... connected.
**ERROR: cannot verify dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com's certificate**, issued by '/
C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA':
  **Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.**
To connect to dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wget`](https://code.google.com/p/osspack32/downloads/detail?name=wget-1.14.exe):

> GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from
>   the Web. It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as
>   retrieval through HTTP proxies.
>
> <sub>Source: [Overview - GNU Wget Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Overview.html#Overview)</sub>

Type `wget.exe -h` or `wget.exe --help` to display basic command line usage. For further information, check the [GNU Wget Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/).

There's a Firefox add-on called [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) which can help you get the correct `wget` command.

**Note** Make sure to enclose the URL inside straight quotes (`"`), because ``` &()[]{}^=;!'+,``~ ``` are reserved characters of the Windows command line interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Third party software is not required to do this. Here are a few ways you can make HTTP requests from Windows PowerShell:

1. [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)
2. [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx)
3. [System.Net.WebClient](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/use-net-webclient-class-powershell-scripts-access-web-data)

If you insist on using third party software, you could use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).